postgresql function not raising exception
Im trying to test out pg_input_is_valid & pg_input_error_info and it doesnt seem to work.
From the below example i expect it to raise a message that 56.7899999 does not meet the criteria. Any ideas why there is no raised exception?
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION input_check(t int[])
RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
    current int; 
    ok int := 0;  
    e text;
BEGIN
    FOREACH current IN ARRAY t LOOP
        IF pg_input_is_valid(current, 'numeric(5,2)') THEN
            ok := ok + 1;
        ELSE
            SELECT message, detail
            INTO e
            FROM pg_input_error_info(current, 'numeric(5,2)');
            RAISE NOTICE 'Skipping [%] because it is not valid: %', current, e;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN ok;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION

postgres=#  SELECT input_check(ARRAY['12.34', '56.7899999']);
-[ RECORD 1 ]--
input_check | 2


raise exception for input value '56.7899999'

56.7899999 is valid.  Try select '56.7899999'::numeric(5,2); or select pg_input_is_valid('56.7899999', 'numeric(5,2)'); to see for yourself.

my understanding is that "precision" is the total number of digits, which is set to 5 (including digits before and after the decimal point).
And for "scale" is the number of digits after the decimal point is 2. This was my logic being used

If you want to check whether the value was rounded, try adding another test like '57.7899999'::numeric(5,2) = '57.7899999'::numeric

I am not seeing how this function is working with the inputs provided, I get ERROR:  function input_check(text[]) does not exist. I suspect you have overloaded the function and have another version that accepts a TEXT array. In psql do \df input_check to verify. FYI, this SELECT input_check(ARRAY[12.34, 56.7899999]); won't work either I get ERROR:  function input_check(numeric[]) does not exist.

To get the function to run I changed it to:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.input_check(t text[])
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    current text;
    ok int := 0;
    e text;
BEGIN
    FOREACH current IN ARRAY t LOOP
        IF pg_input_is_valid(current, 'numeric(5,2)') THEN
            ok := ok + 1;
        ELSE
            SELECT message, detail
            INTO e
            FROM pg_input_error_info(current, 'numeric(5,2)');
            RAISE NOTICE 'Skipping [%] because it is not valid: %', current, e;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN ok;
END
$function$

Running the above still yielded:
SELECT input_check(ARRAY['12.34', '56.7899999']);
 input_check 
-------------
           2

The reason is that per Functions info:

pg_input_is_valid ( string text, type text ) → boolean
Tests whether the given string is valid input for the specified data type; ...

As this shows:
select 56.7899999::numeric(5,2);
 numeric 
---------
   56.79

56.7899999 is a valid input versus something like:
select '56.7899999'::integer;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "56.7899999"
LINE 1: select '56.7899999'::integer;

